# Wrapping the whole C++ application to java?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I currently work for a company which gave me an application implemented by a former student. They completely wrapped (even the main) an existing C++ application with SWIG.

The application was first designed to work on  a desktop and now they want to make it work on an android phone.

My questions are:

1. Is that possible for the application to work knowing they didn't succeed to wrap all 
   the libraries?
2. Is there another way to do this?
3. Is it necessary to write the main in Java and call the C++ libraries?

Any idea will be welcome!

Comment: main() is the entry point for any Java app.

Comment: What does that C++ application do?

Comment: The application is actually identifying and verify a person hand. they used Torch to do the learning.

Comment: Sudhanshu: so main must be written in java is that right?

Comment: Just to be sure, you have source code for the entire C++ application (including libraries)?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes I have everything in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have doubts about there is a automatic utility like SWIG will work to convert PC -> Android - Android OS have significantly different architecture.

Look at [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) - it is a development kit supporting the features called JNI in usual Java applications.
You can include C++ libraries in your Android applications with Android NDK. So it is the way to develop cross-platform applications.

Comment: I'm not expert in programming but let me ask you this question: You said include C++ libraries, so how about C++ programs?

Comment: You can divide your C++ program to "library" part and "entry point". You can reuse library part with Android NDK. "Entry point" cannot be reused.